# 2 different broad leaf milky sap weeds in flower beds

Tags: identification, weeds

First year we have seen these, pics attached below. Only have one of the plant I thought was teasel, but I was told it was not.
The second plant is in three different beds with multiple encounters. Any assistance identifying them would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Jay

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to show two images? Only one is visible. A single leaf is thin information for an identification; if you have a picture of the plant in situ that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

This one looks like Lactuca serriola, commonly known as prickly lettuce, compass plant, or milk thistle. As Colin states, a single leaf can be problematic for identification purposes, but I've seen enough of it that I would bet that's what this is. If it is, get rid of it now. It develops a dandelion-like seed head and will become a chronic pest.

Comment: I immediately thought of prickly lettuce too, but typically prickly lettuce is more prickly than that. The leaf looks soft and easy to handle. It may be a different plant of the lettuce family.